# Laravel get latest projects ordered by project end date that is eminent first

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to write a scope to fetch projects for the currently logged in user. If the currently logged in user has a `view-all-projects` permission then I want to list all the projects in the system, otherwise I want to list projects that the logged in user created or projects that the logged in user is assigned to through tasks. I tried to write the scope below in `Project` model:

```
public function scopeForUser($query, User $user)
  {
    if ($user->can('view-all-projects')) {
      return $query->withBudget()
        ->with(['customer:id,company_id' => ['company:id,name']])
        ->latest()
        ->orderBy('end_date', 'desc');
    }

    return $query->withBudget()
      ->with(['customer:id,company_id' => ['company:id,name']])
      ->where(function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->where('user_id', $user->id)
          ->orWhereHas('users', function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('users.id', $user->id);
          })
          ->orWhereHas('tasks', function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
          });
      })
      ->latest()
      ->orderBy('end_date', 'desc');
  }
```

The `withBudget` is scope like below

```
public function scopeWithBudget($query)
  {
    return $query->addSelect(['budget' => function ($subQuery) {
      $subQuery->selectRaw('sum(cost)')
        ->from('tasks')
        ->whereColumn('project_id', 'projects.id');
    }]);
}
```

So far it does work but not precisely. At times it fetches just a few projects when I know the logged in user is an admin and has all permissions, also the projects get arranged in a descending order of I think `created_at` instead of `end_date`

Any ideas how I can fix the issue? If you need more information, please let me know

**Edit**
The following snippet works if I remove some of the queries:

```
if ($user->hasPermissionTo('view-all-projects')) {
      return $query->latest();
    } else {
      return $query->where(function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->where('user_id', $user->id)
          ->orWhereIn('id', function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->select('project_id')
              ->from('tasks')
              ->where('user_id', $user->id);
          });
      });
    }
```

And then I am fetching projects in an action like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Actions;

use App\Models\Project;
// use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class ListProjects
{

  public function __invoke(): View
  {
    $projects = Project::forUser(auth()->user())->get();

    return view('projects.index', ['projects' => $projects, 'projectsCount' => $projects->count()]);
  }
}
```

While the snippet above works, but it does not do one thing (forget about the eager-loading for now) but I need the projects to be listed according to the time remaining before deadline. So it should list projects that are almost expiring soon, to projects that have more time to projects that have already expired in that order

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with the ordering is likely that you're calling `latest()` as well as `orderBy('end_date', 'desc')` as `latest()` works off of `created_at`. You probably don't need that `latest()` call at all since you're adding your own ordering anyway.

As for the user scoping issue, I'm wondering if the fact that you're using two `orWhereHas` calls instead of a `whereHas` and an `orWhereHas` could be causing an issue here in `scopeForUser`.

Maybe another approach could look like this:

```php
public function scopeForUser($query, User $user)
  {
    if ($user->can('view-all-projects')) {
      return $query->withBudget()
        ->with(['customer:id,company_id' => ['company:id,name']])
        ->orderBy('end_date', 'desc');
    }

    return $query->withBudget()
      ->with(['customer:id,company_id' => ['company:id,name']])
      ->where('user_id', $user->id)
      ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('users.id', $user->id);
          })
          ->orWhereHas('tasks', function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
          });
      })
      ->orderBy('end_date', 'desc');
  }
```

Comment: While the above snippet works, but it only fetches 10 projects out of the 21 projects I have while the logged in user is an admin.

The following snippet works well when stripped:

if ($user->hasPermissionTo('view-all-projects')) {
      return $query->latest();
    } else {
      return $query->where(function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->where('user_id', $user->id)
          ->orWhereIn('id', function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->select('project_id')
              ->from('tasks')
              ->where('user_id', $user->id);
          });
      });
    }